# My flutter code is not reading the code in the order that I expect it to do it

Tags: firebase, function, flutter, class, dart

[image]

This 3 functions are inside a class, the order in which I use them is the next:

1. The login Query is called.
2. If the password matches the username it will call function `loginAccepted()`;
3. This functions changes the value of a class variable to 1 meaning that the data that was entered is correct.

So far the code works they way. The problem comes now.

[image]

I have a `ElevatedButton` in which I:

1. Call the `loginQuery` function from the other class.
2. If the `userMaster.loginVerification` is 1 which would mean the data was correct, it will show a popup saying it was correct. (`userMaster` is the variable that im using to control the functions of that class.)
3. In case `loginVerification` is not 1 it will also show a popup saying it.

[image]

So then, when i try my code entering a valid username and password it shows this which shows on the left, the console showing in the console the print confirming that the data is a valid user, but then on the right the program shows the popup as if the data I entered is not a valid user.

[image]

Then I type in the console `userMaster.loginVerification` to check whats happening and it shows a 1 which would mean the data I entered was valid but the popup got a 0 for that value which makes no sense.

I don't understand what is happening on my code, I am starting to believe that the functions are the last thing to get executed inside of a `ElevatedButton` or something, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is effectively [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but that is geared towards JS and you'll be confused. It's just `async` programming in general though.

1. Make `loginQuery` return a Future

```
Future<void> loginQuery() async {
  var docs = await Firestore.instance.collection(...).where(...).getDocuments();
  // existing if statement
  if(docs.documents.isEmpty) {
   ...
  } else {
   ...
  }
}
```

2. `await` the Future in your `onPressed`

```
onPressed:() async {
  await userMaster.loginQuery(...);
  // now do your if check
}
```

Comment: I added the async thing that you suggested but it still didnt work, it actually has the exact same outcome, console shows that verification was done properly but the popup doesnt get the number in time to show it.

Comment: @MartinPizarro - post your updated code (not pictures of it either).

Comment: I answered my question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how the function in the class ended up:

```
Future<void> loginQuery(String user, String password) async {
Firestore.instance
    .collection('Usuarios')
    .where('usuario', isEqualTo: user)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
  if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
    var w = docs.documents[0].data;

    if (w['contraseña'] == password) {
      print('Datos verificados correctamente');
      loginAccepted();
    } else {
      print('El usuario no existe o la contraseña no corresponde');
      loginDeclined();
    }
  }
});}
```

Thats how the button ended up:

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await userMaster.loginQuery(
              loginUserController.text, loginPasswordController.text);
          if (userMaster.loginVerification == 1) {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Inicio de sesion correcto.'),
                    ),
                barrierDismissible: true);
          } else {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Credenciales incorrectas.'),
                    ),
                barrierDismissible: true);
          }

          // Navigate back to first route when tapped.
        },
        child: Text('Ingresar'),
      ),
```

Comment: You **did not** do what I said and use `async/await` in `loginQuery`. You **need** to `var docs = await Firestore.instance().collection(...).where(...).getDocuments()`

Comment: I didnt realize about the docs = await part, now I changed it and its working, thank you so much.